# Issue between tablet and messagebox on FormClosing event

Tags: vb.net, tablet

I was working on a WinForms application and ran across a really weird bug. I have an issue with putting a MessageBox in the FormClosing event that caused the main form to resize and kill the display on my custom dialog box. I took every other piece of code out other than the MessageBox to confirm the issue. The issue was not present on a Windows PC Desktop but only on the MS Surface Go. Here is the working code for the FormClosing

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

        If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
            Dim form As New frm_NumEnter
            form.isPassword = True
            form.String1 = closeString
            If form.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
                If form.result = "####" Then
                    form.Close()
                Else
                    'MessageBox.Show("Password is Wrong. Please Retry.") Do not turn this on. Causes display issues.
                    form.Close()
                    Form1_FormClosing(sender, e)
                End If
            Else
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Message box is commented out currently as that is the working code.

Anyone have any idea why this occurs? I have looked for an answer and am unable to find one.

Comment: "kill the display" is going to require psychic debugging.  I can tell that this is not a normal Winforms project, seeing System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs spelled out in full is unusual.  On a machine like the Surface Go you have to worry about its high resolution display.  On recent versions of Win10, the DPI virtualization you probably rely on can be disabled on-the-fly.   The diagnostic is that you use the WPF version of the MessageBox class.  Fix by spelling out System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(...) so you won't load PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: You should not call `Form1_FormClosing(sender, e)` from `Sub Form1_FormClosing`. Better way is to check the password in `form` and only when success use `DialogResult.OK`

Comment: @HansPassant it is a normal WinForms app. That was left over from me trying to solve the issue myself. I tried the more explicit version using ```Forms.MessageBox.Show(...)``` and the did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: So you *did* use the WPF version of MessageBox.  Don't assume this is "normal".

Comment: @HansPassant That must be case. I am using a WinForms VB.Net project. The Form itself inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form. I am not importing the PresentationFramework.dll in the form. I did just the generic call to ```MessageBox.Show(...)``` as I always have. The only thing I changed was the explicit call to Forms. Is there another possible reason that the issue occurred or that the call was not to Windows.System.Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Hans comment.

The issue was that the Surface Go was calling the WPF MessageBox class by default. Using the more explicit call to the MessageBox class of `Forms.MessageBox.Show(...)` solved the issue. This only occurred on the form closing with the application. I am not sure why this is but I speculate it is because WPF does not use the FormClosing Event like WinForms does.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Dim form As New frm_NumEnter
        form.isPassword = True
        form.String1 = "closeString"
        If form.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            If form.result = "####" Then
                form.Close()
                e.Cancel = False
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Password is Wrong. Please Retry.")
                form.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```